# Convert a Pandas Series of date in to weekdays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
    Customer Id     Date        Product
0   001             2020-07-20  tropical fruit
1   002             2020-04-30  whole milk
2   003             2020-09-18  pip fruit
3   004             2020-12-11  other vegetables
4   005             2020-01-02  whole milk
    ...
```

and I want to add a column to keep corresponding weekday.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dt.dayofweek` and `dt.day_name`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['weekday'] = df['Id'].dt.dayofweek
df['weekday name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.day_name()
```

Output:

```
   Customer Id  Date     Product          weekday weekday name
0         1 2020-07-20  tropical fruit       0       Monday
1         2 2020-04-30     whole milk        3     Thursday
2         3 2020-09-18       pip fruit       4       Friday
3         4 2020-12-11     other vegetables  4       Friday
4         5 2020-01-02     whole milk        3     Thursday
```

Answer (score 0):

With something like this :

```py
df["WeekDay"] = df["Date"].to_series().apply(lambda date: date.day_name())
```

You can also add a datetime parsing in the lambda `pd.to_datetime(date)` if Date is a simple string object.